# Can errors for function parameter count mismatches be turned on?

Tags: php, syntax-error, parameter-passing

I have a function that takes just 1 parameter, but i passed it 2 parameters by accident.  It failed silently. I didnt realize that the 2nd parameter was being ignored so it took a while to debug.

Is there a way to turn on error checking for a such a condition?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it is not possible to globally cause an error when more arguments are passed than are specified in the function signature, because PHP supports a variable number of arguments in user-defined functions by way `func_get_args()`, for example.  PHP will report an error (of level `E_WARNING` at the time of writing this answer) if you call a function with *less* arguments than specified in the signature, but it does not report an error if you call the function with *more* arguments than specified in the signature.

It's not quite what you're specifically asking for, but of course you can write code to enforce exactly 1 parameter if you absolutely need this behaviour.

```
function foo($only_param) {
   if (func_num_args() > 1) {
      trigger_error(__FUNCTION__ . "(): Too many params", E_USER_ERROR);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: i dont want to do it for each function.

Comment: @glutz I don't blame you. :)

Answer (score -1):

Set this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Or create your own error handler with

```
set_error_handler('customHandler')
```

and a function like this

```
function customHandler( $error, $string, $page, $line, $contextArray )
{
     //$error will be PHP name (E_ERROR, E_NOTICE, etc)
}
```

Comment: Code should work seemingly with E_ALL unless you are a sloppy coder. It is not recommended for production in the event you missed something on development.

Comment: @AzizSaleh I would say it (E_ALL) is *most definitely* recommended in production, with the right configuration - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/bind-param-between-environment/22662582#22662582

Comment: Updated. Anyone get anywhere?